# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isActive')

Tags: angular

I am getting the below error in angular application, because of this error some of the data not displaying in UI. I am unable to figure out the issue, since it is pointing to the js file. Can anyone please help me how to find out the exact issue.

[image]

Comment: This error seems to occur with a production build. You should try to reproduce the issue with a development build, for example using `ng serve`. Then you should have source mapping and see where exactly the error is thrown.

Comment: your object is undefined means object have nothing and you are accessing the isActive property from undefined object, you can check data in the object  is properly set or not.